# Cannot connect to Cassandra from an application running in Tomcat, but it is successful with Datagrip

Tags: tomcat, cassandra, spring-data, datastax, datastax-java-driver

In Datagrip, I can connect to Cassandra with `sslenabled=true` and set the VM options with

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_truststore_file> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>`.

I tried to simulate the same by creating a `setenv.sh` file in <tomcat_dir>/bin directory with the below content.

`export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_truststore_file> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>"`

But I am still getting this error in the app:

`nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /X.X.X.X:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException...`

Update 9/25:
If not running in tomcat, using the example here https://github.com/radicalbit/cassandra-ssl-client-to-node-example, it is getting that same `NoHostAvailableException` exception.

Comment: the title of the question is misleading, not sure if you can't connect from datagrip or your tomcat server. The first thing that comes to mind is the port, for SSL enabled connections the default port is 9142, did you change the `native_transport_port_ssl` value in your Cassandra yaml?

Comment: you may need to disable hostname validation - that's a common problem

Comment: where/how to do that hostname validation?

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas i am able to connect from datagrip.